# how to access shared file without grant permission for 'storage'

Tags: android, permissions, share

with Nexus 5, os M 6.0.1, and in Camera app select a photo and do ‘share’. In the target app, it gets the Uri from the intent and the filePath.
when do new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile)) it throws: 
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

It is because of permission for ‘storage’ not granted, but don’t want ask user to specifically grant ‘storage’ permission. 
Is there a different way to read the file without permission for ’storage’?

This is how the file path is extracted:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) &&  
    intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {

Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

String filePath;

Cursor cursor = null;
final String column = "_data"; 
final String[] projection = { column };
try {
  cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
       filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);           
  }
} catch(Exception e){
  return getFilePathFromInputStream(context, uri);
}
finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
}

// upto here got filePath =   
   /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170326_184502.jpg

boolean b = false;
try{
   File f2 = new File(filePath);
   b = f2.exists();
} catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("+++ exception e:"+e.getMessage());
} catch(Error e) {
   Log.e("+++ error e:"+e.getMessage());
}

// unto here no exception, then

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));  //<=== here throws

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170326_184502.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: What's the actual `uri` you receive?

Answer (score 2):

Do not extract a file path from that uri.

Just pass the uri to the next app.

Never try to extract file paths from uries. Instead open an input stream for the uri directly. Not a file input stream.

You will have enough troubles passing the uri to the next app.

Well its easy to pass the uri but the next app will not be abls to read from it as you could not transfer the obtained permissions.

What you could do instead is using a content provider to serve the selected file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will try "Never try to extract file paths from uries. Instead open an input stream for the uri directly.".  btw I'm not creating the uri to pass to next app, it is do sharing from the 'camera' app's gallery, my app is the 'next' app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "read the file without permission for ’storage’". You need down targetSdkVersion. You can edit build.gradle file container "applicationId", use "targetSdkVersion 22" on tag "defaultConfig".